# add and delete json list inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

i want to create a page where someone adds 1 or more locations to a contact and right now i have something that looks like this.

```
<div class="input-append" ng-repeat="location in newPartner.partner_location">
    <input class="input-large" type="text" ng-model="location">
    <button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="delLocation1({{$index}})">- {{$index}}</button>
</div>

<div class="input-append">
    <input class="input-large" type="text" ng-model="new_location">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="addLocation1()">+</button>
</div>
```

This is the HTML and the controller looks like this.

```
$scope.newPartner = {'partner_name':'newname','partner_location':['X','Y','Z']};

$scope.addLocation1 = function() {
    $scope.newPartner.partner_location.push($scope.new_location);
    $scope.new_location = "";
}
$scope.delLocation1 = function(id) {
    $scope.newPartner.partner_location.splice(id, 1);
}
```

Now it works great on begin but if i delete some items and add some it suddenly bugs out and starts to delete the previous item instead the one i press - (minus) on.

Is there something i did wrong? Thank you in advance, Daniel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off remove `{{}}` from `ng-click="delLocation1({{$index}})"`. It should be:

```
ng-click="delLocation1($index).
```

Second, I suggest you to add some basic debugger to see what happens with our model when we add new value: `<pre>{{newPartner.partner_location|json}}</pre>`

Third,  I would change the model to:

```
$scope.newPartner = {
        'partner_name': 'newname',
        'partner_location': [{value:'X'}, {value:'Y'}, {value:'Z'}]
    };
```

because, by this way: `['X','Y','Z']` we can't modify our data.

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/680/)**</kbd>

Finally this is our fixed code:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="fessCntrl">
    <div  ng-repeat="location in newPartner.partner_location">
        <input class="input-large" type="text" ng-model="location.value">
        <button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="delLocation1(newPartner.partner_location, $index)">{{$index}}</button>
    </div>
    <div class="input-append">
        <input class="input-large" type="text" ng-model="new_location">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="addLocation1()">+</button>
    </div>        
        <pre>{{newPartner.partner_location|json}}</pre>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var fessmodule = angular.module('myModule', []);

fessmodule.controller('fessCntrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.new_location = "empty";

    $scope.newPartner = {
        'partner_name': 'newname',
        'partner_location': [{value:'X'}, {value:'Y'}, {value:'Z'}]
    };

    $scope.addLocation1 = function () {
        $scope.newPartner.partner_location.push({value:$scope.new_location});
        $scope.new_location = "empty";
    }
    $scope.delLocation1 = function (locations, index) {
        locations.splice(index, 1);
    }
});

fessmodule.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

Comment: wow.. i removed the {{$index}} and let only $index and it seems this fixed the issue.. thank you so much Maxim Shoustin, this is awesome :)